# Error while hide-show functionality using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I am working on hide show functionality using JavaScript

but it occurring error on console for onclick function

I am not getting why this error occurring.

**JAVASCRIPT CODE**

```
<script type="text/javascript">

  function showtabs(id,id1) {
  alert(id);
  alert(id1);
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var flag = document.getElementById(id1);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
   {
      e.style.display = 'none';
      flag.innerHTML = '+';
   }
   else
   {
      e.style.display = 'block';
      flag.innerHTML = '-';
   }  
}
```

**PHP CODE**

```
<?php

$output.='<div class="span6"> 
  <div class="header" onclick="showtabs(my_section,icon);">
  <h1>My Section <span class="iconc" id="icon">+</span></h1>
  </div></div>';
$output.='<div id="my_section" style="display:none;">This is my section</div>';
echo $output;

?>
```

**Error Log**

```
TypeError: e is null
if(e.style.display == 'block')
```

Comment: What about `my_section`

Comment: are you able to get the ids inside showtabs?

Comment: no....it gives me alert like [object HTMLDivElement]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
<html>
<?php 
$output='';

$output.='<div class="span6"> 
  <div class="header" onclick="showtabs(\'my_section\',\'icon\');">
  <h1>My Section <span class="iconc" id="icon">+</span></h1>
  </div></div>';
$output.='<div id="my_section" style="display:none;">This is my section</div>';

?>
<head>
    <title>Sample Eula Agreement</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">

  function showtabs(id,id1) {
  alert(id);
  alert(id1);
   var e = document.getElementById(id);
   var flag = document.getElementById(id1);

   alert(e.style.display);
   if(e.style.display == 'block')
   {
      e.style.display = 'none';
      flag.innerHTML = '+';
   }
   else
   {
      e.style.display = 'block';
      flag.innerHTML = '-';
   }  
}

</script>
<style>

</style>

</head>
<body>
<?php


echo $output;

?>

</body>
</html>
```

You are passing string inside your function but because of the missing quotes, It is reading those as HTML elements. Thats why, e is coming null.

Comment: if i adding line above it gives

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Comment: See the whole code, which I am able to run successfully and it is working perfectly fine.

Comment: but i want to display HTML in php only like i have added code sample above

Comment: Got your point. See the updated code. If you have further issue, feel free to let me know.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the variable e is null. In other words there is no element in the dom with the id that you are passing to the function.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot the quotes. Try this:
    onclick="showtabs('my_section','icon');"

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not selecting id and id1 perfectly

```
var e = document.getElementById('id');   //check here
var flag = document.getElementById('id1');
```

Comment: because it takes parameter as string document.getElementById(elementID)  //elementID is string

Answer (score 0):

just change the code of php of `$output` variable `onclick=showtabs("my_section","icon")` because you pass the id without double quats, So its react like object